# Creating an online rock, paper, scissors game in c++

Tags: c++

Ok, so I've been doing some research on how to create a rock, paper, scissors game in c++ and that is pretty simple. I wanted to some how create an application that you would download from a website that I currently have. They would launch the application and it would have the option of playing single player, or multiplayer. The multiplayer one is the one I am having trouble and I'm not sure what to do. I want it to be able to find a match and they could play a game best of 5 and the winner gets xp. If you have any link or anywhere to help me get started, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Too broad a question for stackoverflow. I dunno how to mark it as such or don't have privileges to do so.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz You can flag questions at 15 reputation - you are clearly above that. And if you think that it is too broad - flag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to develope your application you mainly need:

1. A server application: that access in the database, manage users, manage games
2. A client application: that request the available games and, in general, work on the client for managing the game. (**Important**: you need to sync it with the server)
3. A database: to store the matches, the users' info, etc.

For implementing communcations between server and client [sockets](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) is what you need.

For managing multiple connections and games you need to use [threads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) on your server.

Comment: seriously, thank you. atleast i know where to get started.  Thanks again.